# How to configure Java Network Proxy Settings for domain computers

Tags: windows, domain, java, scripting, deployment

I need to set the Network Proxy Settings to Direct Connection, for computers on our domain. 
I have looked at the unattended setup configurations, as well as the deployment.properties file, and didn't see an option to set it to Direct Connection.

Are there any alternate means to set this? ex...logon script, vbscript, powershell, GPO,  (would be great, but I couldn't find anything on this)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

check out [Deployment Configuration File and Properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/properties.html) part of jdk documentation. they mention there properties that can be used to enforce proxied access.